# XOR between floats in python

Tags: python, xor

I am implementing conversion from RGB to Yxy color and the pseudocode guides me to execute XOR (^) operation on two float variables. How I can do this in python? I get this error:

unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'float'

Take a look at this pseudocode: http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=02#text2.

Comment: Do you know what the XOR is supposed to achieve semantically? Please link or include the guide in your post.

Comment: Could you show the pseudo-code? And maybe it's not XOR but exponent (which in some languages is the `^` character)?

Comment: maybe there is another way of doing what you need, other than XOR

Comment: Do you mean RGB to the CIE XYZ color space? XORing float values makes no sense, can you show us the pseudocode? Just edit your question and add it.

Comment: Yes that's most likely an exponent. Try using the [`powf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) function.

Comment: ^ means power in the pseudocode :)

Comment: Please update your question, maybe just delete it as you have led us on a wild goose chase.

Comment: And I happened to catch that wild goose but have to release it in wilderness.

Comment: @Abhijit We both caught it, you showed one way to do what I got downvoted for.

Answer (score 4):

There is no inbuilt support for xoring floating point numbers. Instead you have to implement one using the `struct` module

```
>>> from struct import pack, unpack
>>> def xor_float(f1, f2):
    f1 = int(''.join(hex(ord(e))[2:] for e in struct.pack('d',f1)),16)
    f2 = int(''.join(hex(ord(e))[2:] for e in struct.pack('d',f2)),16)
    xor = f1 ^ f2
    xor = "{:016x}".format(xor)
    xor = ''.join(chr(int(xor[i:i+2],16)) for i in range(0,len(xor),2))
    return struct.unpack('d',xor)[0]

>>> xor_float(10.25,10.25)
0.0
>>> xor_float(10.25,0.00)
10.25
```

**Note** This example assumes, that the floating point number is a 64 bit float, as natively supported by Python

---

I should have seen your pseudo-code before jumping in to solving this problem. The caret `^` in the pseudo-code is power rather than xor and in python raising a number to power (including float) is done through `**` or `math.pow`

Comment: got `TypeError: ord()` expected string of length `1`, but `int` found @Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply bit wise operators to integers. So convert the floats to integer first.

Comment: This will result in loosing information (and having a wrong result from XOR) because the int() cast on a float is always the integer part

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo if that's the point, just use `round(number, digits)`

Comment: @whatyouhide and that's where you will get another float, not suitable for a XOR again

Comment: If you work on RGB images, the values are usually, for each channel, 0..255,  but some libraries present them as 0.0...1.0. Maybe conversion to int via `int_value = int(round(255*float_value))`

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo `int(round(number))` will round to the next integer.

Comment: @whatyouhide still there is information loss. not suitable for the op (on RGB, 2.55 is different than 2.20). Also, int(3.4) and int(round(3.4, <any_number>)) both yeld (as expected) 3. Still not correct :)

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I didn't say to cast it to integer, I said to convert it, that implies using whatever means is needed to make a whole number. I know that cast will lose the fraction as will floor or round. e.g. thorstenkranz's comment

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo obviously you'll lose information, I wasn't suggesting a solution to your problem, just saying that there are ways to avoid and integer cast. :)

Comment: I do have no problems at all, especially with floats and ints :P

Answer (score 0):

```python3
import struct, math

def fxor(a, b):
  rtrn = []
  a = struct.pack('d', a)
  b = struct.pack('d', b)
  for ba, bb in zip(a, b):
    rtrn.append(ba ^ bb)

  return struct.unpack('d', bytes(rtrn))[0]

print(fxor(math.pi, math.pi)) #0.0
print(fxor(math.e, math.pi))  #1.7551491316820714e-308
print(fxor(math.pi, 0))       #3.141592653589793
```

`64-bit float` `xor`. This performs an `xor` operation on each bit that makes up the floating point and returns it as a `double` and/or `64-bit float`

Comment: I don't know if this still helps anyone but there are reasons to xor floats and this is a pretty straightforward way. However, in pseudocode, `^` does mean exponent. Not every language revolves around python...